# Restrictions on Drupal subscriptions to forums

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, forum, subscriptions

I've got a Drupal 6 site with existing forums (and Advanced Forums) that we need to add email subscriptions to. I've got the Subscriptions module installed and showing but it also shows on all other parts of the site.

I'm sure there's a way to restrict it to forums only but it doesn't seem to be through the Subscriptions settings pages.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved this but have worked around it by using the Notifications module instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can control the display of subscription links for different content types & Taxonomies here: /admin/settings/subscriptions

Go to "Blocked content types" and block the required content types.
Similarly under "Taxonomy settings" section.

Comment: I've blocked everything except 'forum' but the box still appears on the homepage.